# How to see Gmail message subject when scrolling down?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail the message subject is at the top of the page and at the tab title.
When I scroll down a conversation I can't see the subject and a lot of times the tab title is too narrow for me to get the full subject.
Is there another way I can see the subject when I'm at a bottom of a conversation?

Comment: You can always try hovering over the tab name and a small popup will appear with the email subject (though it is not necessarily the whole line if it is quite long).

Comment: thats quite sad, would have been great if gmail devs can be little more creative to add a feature to stick mail subject .